# Dynamic Analysis of PHP Web Applications to identify work flow deviations

Tags: php, security, dynamic

I am trying to learn on Web Application security. I worked with tools that do static Analysis like RIPS, Pixy. Also did profiling of web-applications using xdebug and kcachegrind.
 Now I am trying to research more on Dynamic Analysis. I would like to identify work flow deviations from call graphs generated during profiling. 
Is it possible to do such an analysis??
If so can you suggest me any references or tools that achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some projects/papers addressing this need:

1. [PHP Vulnerability Hunter](http://www.autosectools.com/PHP-Vulnerability-Scanner)
2. [PHP Analyzer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpa/)
3. [Static and Dynamic Analysis for PHP 
   Security](http://domino.research.ibm.com/comm/research_projects.nsf/pages/phpsecurity.pubs.html/$FILE/NYPHP_final.pdf) (pdf)

The third item is an academic presentation from 2006, so it may be a little out of date while the first resource seems the most mature DA testing tool I've seen.  You might also look into the [Monte Carlo Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) as a way of throwing arbitrary input at a system to test its robustness, particular if you deal with numerical or statistical data.

Comment: Thank you for your input.I found those useful. What I am looking for is more like Multi-Module State Analyzer. Are analysers like MiMoSA being implemented  in the industry for better security of web applications?

Comment: Glad it helped.  I looked into MMSA for PHP and the closest I can see is a [presentation (ppt)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.northwestern.edu%2F~ychen%2Fclasses%2Fcs450-s10%2Flectures%2FwebSecTutorial_part2.pptx&ei=n1dBT5P4J6i-0AGu0JXuBw&usg=AFQjCNFldMGIKUQb9bCUtX5XFL2RjwyCnA) that gives some PHP examples on page 36.  I don't think there are any toolsets because the vulnerability is tightly related to the data flow of the application.

Comment: I was actually trying to implement MiMOSA given in that presentation. Are there any tools for data flow analysis like visio. Can the application state variables be obtained and stored while profiling it dynamically using xdebug

Comment: I wish I could be more help, @user1168647 but you may be at the leading edge here.  If you build such a tool I would love to know of it and potentially collaborate.

Answer (score 4):

There is one free tool, [Paros - for web application security assessment](http://www.parosproxy.org/)

Its not too complicated, easy to work with.